# CSS Animations trying to avoid jerkyness

Tags: css, css-animations

I have built a ken burn effect and some how managed to make it smooth. The problem is that when the user scrolls the screen on a touchscreen device the animation then jerks.

I though by pausing the animation on scroll might fix this but it has not. Animation is fine until the user scrolls then it becomes jerky. I have set up a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/gxUhH/58/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a long shot: use `-webkit-translate-3d` instead of `-webkit-translate`. The former triggers iOS's hardware acceleration which might help you in what seems to be a performance issue.